# Duality in projective spaces

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $V^*= Hom(V,\mathbb{K})$. Let $\mathbb{P}(V)$ be the set of all hyperplanes of $V$. If $F \in V^*$, why can I say that $\mathbb{P}(Ker^*(F)) \in \{hyperplanes \; of \; \mathbb{P}(V^*) \}$? I found it in a master thesis but I think that the correct space for $\mathbb{P}(Ker^*(F))$ is $ \{hyperplanes \; of \; \mathbb{P}(V) \}$. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What does $Ker^\ast (F)$ mean? Something like $Ker(F)^\ast$, the set of hyperplanes of the hyperplane determined by $F$?

Comment: @rschwieb I actually don't know. At the beginning I thought that it meant $ Ker^*(F)= Ker(F)\{0} $, but now I am wondering if maybe it's just the dual space.